# Why is SSH still asking for my passphrase on a private key provided by the server admin? (No passphrase set on private key)

Tags: terminal, ssh

I'm being prompted for a passphrase each time I try to connect with my ssh key.

```
$ ssh user@server.ip -i .ssh/private_key
```

I was given these credentials (private key) by the server admin, *so I cannot regenerate the key*, and there is nothing wrong with the credentials. I copied/pasted the key exactly (there is no botching of dashes with hyphens due to a mail client, etc). I verified there are no spaces / line break issues with vim, an the same issue happens. [Permissions are set correctly (to 0600).](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18458/password-dialog-appears-when-ssh-private-key-permissions-are-set-to-0600)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I copied the data from the SSH key itself, but not the header/footer, and that was the entire issue. Note to self: make sure to copy everything from the start of the line `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` to the end of the line `END RSA PRIVATE KEY` including all dashes.

In other words, the private key is not...

```
4OoXTO0cqjtyd7rPWaKeKHgmF5Zu9h7AdZCIJuUTpbBhzER7nW1tMZVPAHMed3r
...
Z9BX7lae9FN/dv5TSAFdSG1Ow011ZvENw25l4mKMPREcHRvDMedeL6oQSBL2m9c
```

... but rather ...

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
4OoXTO0cqjtyd7rPWaKeKHgmF5Zu9h7AdZCIJuUTpbBhzER7nW1tMZVPAHMed3r
...
Z9BX7lae9FN/dv5TSAFdSG1Ow011ZvENw25l4mKMPREcHRvDMedeL6oQSBL2m9c
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```